# Hetzner IP Subnet on Windows 10 VM

Tags: windows, networking, kvm-virtualization, windows-10, hetzner

I have created a brouter (bridge router) on my CentOS 7 KVM Host machine. I am trying to assign an IP from an addon subnet that Hetzner has provided.

The following is the working configuration for a CentOS 7 guest that I have running also:

*ifcfg-eth0:*

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=138.201.XXX.162
IPADDR1=138.201.XXX.162
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
NETMASK1=255.255.255.255
SCOPE="peer 138.201.YYY.207"
```

*route-eth0:*

```
ADDRESS0=0.0.0.0
NETMASK0=0.0.0.0
GATEWAY0=138.201.YYY.207
```

I am not too sure how to do this configuration on a Windows 10 guest. This is what I currently have set but it does not work:

[Windows 10 VM - IPv4 Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7UXn.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the IP from the Hetzner subnet, a static route must be added.
This question might help: [Windows static routes w/o specifying gateway (next hop)](https://serverfault.com/questions/115654/windows-static-routes-w-o-specifying-gateway-next-hop)

In case this won't help, there are several more ways to configure your additional Hetzner subnet. 
For example by using virtual network interfaces, 
iptables NAT and just assign local IP's to the guest-machines. 
I have a setup at Hetzner like this at the moment and it's easier to manage than dealing with public ip's on the guest-machines.
If your system is not "live" yet, you should consider a reconfiguration of the network.